# python code inside details tag in markdown

Tags: python, html, markdown

Hi I am using jupyter notebooks in sphinx to create documentation. Below is the code, i want to toggle for hide/show using details tag in a markdown cell.

---

````html
<details>
  <summary><font size="4" color="darkred"><b>My Solution</b></font></summary>
      ```python 
      import math
      %matplotlib inline 
      plt.xlabel('Area of triangle')    
      ```
</details>
````

---

The resulant snippet doesn't reflect python highlighting on execution
(I don't intend to run the python code, it is just to hide and show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point1: There need to be an linebreak, i.e. an empty line after <summary> line

Point 2: The second problem is the indentation. I don't know why, but when I used less than 4 white spaces to indent the python '''python line, it worked.

````
<details>
  <summary><font size="4" color="darkred"><b>My Solution</b></font></summary>
    
  ```python
      import math
      %matplotlib inline 
      plt.xlabel('Area of triangle')
  ```
</details>
````

To use details tag with nested hide/show containing python blocks

````
<details>
  <summary><font size="4" color="darkred"><b>My Solution</b></font></summary>
    
  ```python
      import math
      %matplotlib inline 
      plt.xlabel('Area of triangle')
  ```

  <details>
    <summary><font size="2" color="Blue"><b>See hints</b></font></summary>
    
  ```python
      import math
      %matplotlib inline 
      plt.xlabel('Area of triangle')
  ```
    
  </details>

    
</details>
````

I am adding the image of the corrections below:[Correct code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W9BC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab.
Your code looks correct but maybe in Jupiter notebook are you missing to choose markdown option?

Comment: No, I was using a markdown type cell. But, thanks for the input.